# CreateProcess kills PC

Tags: c, windows, createprocess

I tryed to write a little brute force program. The password program returns 1 when the password is right and 0 when wrong.
So its very easy an short.

In the bruteforce program I call the pw program with createprocess().

My problem is that when trying to crack the pw my pc gets very slow and I have to restart.

Here is the code.

```
STARTUPINFO         siStartupInfo;
PROCESS_INFORMATION piProcessInfo;

memset(&siStartupInfo, 0, sizeof(siStartupInfo));
memset(&piProcessInfo, 0, sizeof(piProcessInfo));

siStartupInfo.cb = sizeof(siStartupInfo);
char newKey[10] = " ";
strcat(newKey, key);

if(CreateProcess("C:\\Users\\Christoph\\Dropbox\\test\\bin\\Debug\\test.exe",     // Application name
                 newKey,                 // Application arguments
                 0,
                 0,
                 FALSE,
                 CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE,
                 0,
                 0,                              // Working directory
                 &siStartupInfo,
                 &piProcessInfo) == FALSE)
```

Do I have to kill the processes by my self?
At the first few seconds i get over 1k keys per second.
Can you please help me?

Thanks

Comment: There is no problem with `CreateProcess()`.  The problem is in `test.exe`.

Comment: Aye, you should limit the number of test processes allowed to be running. If this were real world, I would guess you would only ever have one test process and feed it passwords by some other means than start-up arguments.

Comment: Sure?  test.exe just makes an easy if and else and returns an int.

Comment: Creating a process is a very expensive operation. Starting a new process for each key will give absolutely horrible performance.

Comment: hmm should i rather use threads? But this cant be the only problem. Could it be that the processes doesent get killed?

Comment: Well, how many processes are you spawning at a time? Are you waiting until each process is stopped? Also there are two handles being passed back to you that you both need to close for each process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going to take a bit of a guess here, but are you cleaning up the handles returned to you by [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx%20CreateProcess) in the last parameter's [`PROCESS_INFORMATION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684873%28v=vs.85%29.aspx%20PROCESS_INFORMATION) structure?

The `hProcess` and `hThread` handles need to be closed when not using them, or else you'll leak handles just like a memory leak.

That being said, spawning a new process for each key to be tried in a brute-force manner is highly inefficient. `CreateProcess` is relatively expensive, and will not give you reasonable performance.

Furthermore, and this is my personal observation, so there is no real proof backing this, I have seen Windows having trouble handling a large number of processes. From observing Google Chrome, which spawns each tab in a new process, I have noticed the system becoming relatively slow, with the occasional system-wide hangs. Especially in the early days of Chrome.

Comment: Yes this was my question. Thanks. But very slow. Only getting about 300 keys per second. On Ubuntu with fork i get 1000 keys per second.

Comment: @user281874 Fork works in a different way than CreateProcess does, but even so forking is not really high-performance. If you want to get more serious, you should look into multiple threads.

Comment: But how is it possible to start an external program in a thread? The external program needs a process right? Can i run an external program without createprocess? Is a Shellscript a better way? Thanks

Comment: @user281874 The best solution is to rework the code from the external program into your own. If, however, this is not your executable and you do not have access to the source code, then you are indeed left with `CreateProcess` only, and there's not much else you can do. Best thing to keep the system running smoothly is to limit the amount of processes you start, and only start a new process when an old one terminates.

Comment: I have the source but I want to simulate that the program is protected by a password. Hmm okay i try shellExecute und system() maybe the performance gets a bit better. Thanks very much